# How to check whether a video is audible?

Tags: javascript

A video has audio track and its volume is not zero or muted, but this video is not audible due to its audio track is in total quietness. I want to know how to check whether a video is audible, so I can toggle  functions upon.

I found how to check whether a video has audio track from here. @upuoth's method works most browsers except IE10+. @brefd.it works for IE10+ but I didn't know how to use his code (please explain to me)

@upuoth's code

```
 document.getElementById("video").addEventListener("loadeddata", function()     {
if (typeof this.webkitAudioDecodedByteCount !== "undefined") {
// non-zero if video has audio track
if (this.webkitAudioDecodedByteCount > 0)
  console.log("video has audio");
else
  console.log("video doesn't have audio");
}
else if (typeof this.mozHasAudio !== "undefined") {
// true if video has audio track
if (this.mozHasAudio)
  console.log("video has audio");
else
  console.log("video doesn't have audio");
}
else
console.log("can't tell if video has audio");
});
```

@brefd's code

```
function hasAudio (video) {
return video.mozHasAudio ||
Boolean(video.webkitAudioDecodedByteCount) ||
Boolean(video.audioTracks && video.audioTracks.length);
}

var video = document.querySelector('video');
if(hasAudio(video)) {
console.log("video has audio");
} else{
console.log("video doesn't have audio");
}
```

I prepared three video clips, one with an audio track, one without audio track and one with an audio track but isn't audible. The code I found above only works for the fisrt two clips but for the third one. Please let the alert be "not audible" when playing the third clip by using the [code from JSfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/nojava/58xzvda9/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the merged code of above that you can replace with in your JSFiddle:

```
document.getElementById("myVideo").addEventListener("loadeddata", function() {
    if (typeof this.webkitAudioDecodedByteCount !== "undefined") {
        if (this.webkitAudioDecodedByteCount > 0)
            alert("This video has a track");
        else
            alert("no track");
    } else if (typeof this.mozHasAudio !== "undefined") {
        if (this.mozHasAudio)
            alert("This video has a track");
        else
            alert("no track");
    } else if (typeof this.audioTracks !== "undefined") {
        if (this.audioTracks && this.audioTracks.length)
            alert("audible");
        else 
            alert("not audible");
    } else
        alert("Not sure");
});
```

Unfortunately, I doubt if there would be a way to detect "not audible" audio tracks.

Comment: thanks @cypark how about detecting when an audio track‘s loudness is getting lower to a certain level ?

Comment: By nature, it is not possible for browsers to check audio decibel. There is a draft version of [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) that would meet your needs, but it is not production ready yet. If you just want to experiment, [this plugin](https://github.com/jasonpecor/DecibelMeter) might work for you. But again, I think these are only for experiments as of now.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to check whether a video file has audio or not, one of which is to use `mozHasAudio`, `video.webkitAudioDecodedByteCount` and `video.audioTracks?.length` properties of video, clean and simple...

```
const video = component.node.querySelector("video");
video.onloadeddata = function() {
    if ((typeof video.mozHasAudio !== "undefined" && video.mozHasAudio) ||
        (typeof video.webkitAudioDecodedByteCount !== "undefined" && video.webkitAudioDecodedByteCount > 0) ||
        Boolean(video.audioTracks?.length)) {
        console.log("This video has audio tracks.");
    } else {
        console.log("This video has no audio tracks.");
    }            
};
```